# Why does my loop continue as an infinite loop?

Tags: python

I have a bit of code and I'm having trouble understanding why the loop is an infinite loop even though I have an else condition which should end the loop.

```py
def add1(*args):
    total = 0
    add = True

    for num in args:
        while add == True:
            if num!=6:
                total = total + num
            else:
                add = False
    return total

add1(1,2,3,6,1)
```

My question is, I have an else statement that changes the add to 'False' hence the loop should stop but for some reason it doesn't.

However, if I make a slight alteration to the code as such, it stops:

```py
def add1(*args):
    total = 0
    add = True

    for num in args:
        while add == True:
            if num!=6:
                total = total + num
                break
            else:
                add = False
    return total

add1(1,2,3,6,1)
```

basically, adding a break.
I don't understand how expert python coders actually interpret 'break' in their minds. I've read articles on break, but still can't seem to understand it quite as well.
I don't understand why the 'break' is needed and why the 'else' can't suffice.

Comment: I ran the code at the top and it worked (although with some error) without entering an infinite loop. Are you sure that's the problem?

Comment: your `while add` loop is within a different loop which does not break when `add==False`, therefore it goes to the last argument (1) and executes an indefinite loop..

Comment: @BlueRineS still a bit confused.....shouldn't it stop once the while = False?

Comment: @VedBrahmbhatt The thing is, it goes in the `for` loop to iterate through each args, so the first time it "calls" `1`, and stays stuck to it because it will always be different than `6` and `add` will always be true. When you `break` you stop the `while` loop each time it's different than `6`, and then you can continue iterating on your `args`. Does it seems clearer ?

Comment: what @Nqsir said, it is easily noticed by a print(num) before the while, and a print (add) after the else block, you will see that the while loop is infinite because the else condition is never met

Comment: so, you're saying the break forces the while to end and goes back up to the for loop? I know that breaks end a loop, but I wasn't sure if they also start another loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you enter the `for` loop, `num` gets the value `1` (the first value in `args`). Then you enter the `while` loop (since `add` is True). Now, because `num` does not equal `6`, you enter the `if` block, so the `else` block does NOT executes. Then, you just return to the `while` loop, and the value of `num` doesn't change. Then, because `num` does not equal `6` (remember it didn't change, it is still `1`), once again you enter the `if` block, and so on until you terminate the program.

When you add the `break`, you exit the closest loop, which in this case is the `while` loop, so the `for` loop continues, until `num` gets the value `6`, and `add` becomes `False`. When that happens, the `while` loop never executes again.

Comment: I think I get it. Only the closest enclosing loop will re-run right? That seems to be a default python rule. Like, once the while loop it ends it won't automatically go to the for loop and while loop again? Also, the break statement breaks the while loop and goes back to the next enclosing loop, right? As in break doesn't go the next loop below if there was one?

Answer (score 0):

```
def add1(*args):
    total = 0
    add = True

    for num in args:
        if add == True:
            if num!=6:
                total = total + num
            else:
                add = False
                break      #breaking the for loop for better performance only.
    return total

add1(1,2,3,6,1)
```

this adds till 6 is not encountered. you are using while loop unnecessarily. you have to break the infinite loop by some condition and that condition is when num!=6. even your else part can break the infinite while loop, but according to me the while loop itself is unnecessary.

Comment: If you really want to get better performance you can also get rid of the `add` variable

Answer (score 0):

I believe the purpose of your code is to sum up elements in *args up to first occurrence of number 6. If that is the case, the while loop is redundant here. Changing the first code snippet:

```
def add1(*args):
    total = 0

    for num in args:
        if num != 6:
            total = total + num
        else:
            break
    return total


add1(1, 2, 3, 6, 1)
```

---

What actually happens in your original code is that the *num* variable doesn't change in any way when iterating in while loop, so it never enters the else part, effectively getting stuck on the first input argument that is not 6, see below:

```
def add1(*args): # [1, 2, 3, 6, 1]
    total = 0
    add = True

    for num in args:  # first element is 1. num = 1
        while add == True:
            if num != 6:  # num = 1 always
                total = total + num
                # adding break here gets out of the while loop on first iteration, changing num = 2
                # and later to 3, 6...
            else:  # else is never reached
                add = False
    return total


add1(1, 2, 3, 6, 1)
```

Answer (score -1):

You should change the below codes:

from

```
if num != 6:
```

to

```
if total != 6:
```

Comment: Nope, this is not what he asked for ^^

Comment: Oh, yes I see. It seems I misunderstood.